# Select sibling div above current div

Tags: css, select, html, siblings

I'm trying to make a harmonica effect by changing the height of divs when hovering over another one.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<html><body>
  <div class="section1"></div>
  <div class="section2"></div>
  <div class="section3"></div>
  <div class="section4"></div>
</body></html>
```

Every section has a height of 25%.
When hovering over section1, all the other divs should reduce in size while section1 expands. This is easily done with the following CSS:

```
.section1 {
  height: 40%;
}
.section1:hover ~ div:not(section1) {
  height: 20%;
}
```

The problem is that the ~ selector only selects sibling divs that are below the current div. So if I use the same code for section2, only section3 and section4 will be affected. Section1 will have it's original height of 25% because it's above the current div.

Can I solve this problem with just CSS?

Comment: are you sure you dont want to use jquary or javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Put a wrapper around your sections and reduce their height on hover on the wrapper. Then increase the height of the one section you are hovering.

[**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3620483)

**HTML** becomes:

```
<div class='section-wrapper'>
    <div class="section1"></div>
    <div class="section2"></div>
    <div class="section3"></div>
    <div class="section4"></div>
</div>
```

Relevant **CSS**:

```
.section-wrapper {
    height: 500px;
}
.section-wrapper div {
    height: 25%;
    outline: dotted 1px;
}
.section-wrapper:hover div {
    height: 20%;
}
.section-wrapper div:hover {
    height: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sESTV/)

HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section1">1</div>
            <div class="section2">2</div>
            <div class="section3">3</div>
            <div class="section4">4</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS    ​

```
.container:hover div {
    height:20px;
}
.container .section1,.container .section1:hover,
.container .section2,.container .section2:hover,
.container .section3,.container .section3:hover,
.container .section4,.container .section4:hover{
  height: 50px;
}

​
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Add a parent container to the sections

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="section1">section1</div>
  <div class="section2">section2</div>
  <div class="section3">section3</div>
  <div class="section4">section4</div>
</div
```

And style them as

```
.parent div{height: 25%; border:solid 1px #f00}
.parent:hover div{height: 20%; }
.parent div:hover {height: 40%; }
```